# Symfony2 the template does not support the "bundle" parameter

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assets, assetic

I'm working on a project with friends, using git. Yesterday, a friend pushed some stuff relative to his bundle, but after I pull it, I got this strange error message

**An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("The template does not support the "bundle" parameter.") in "layout.html.twig".**

I figured out that it's linked to assetic (I tried to remove all my assets and it worked again, but without js nor css files) and it's doing that with all my pages.

The point is, it doesnt work for me, but it works for him. Now, I tried to `cache:clear` an uncountable amount of times, `doctrine:schema:update` too. I just want to know what could be the cause of this error, why it's not working so suddenly, and if there's anything I can do about it...

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546444/symfony2-twig-including-header-with-assets-not-working) even though it's not exactly my problem, doesnt work. Here is my assetic configuration in config.yml, even though wasnt modified

```
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        []

#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
assets:
    jquery: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys !

**Edit : where my problem appears to be**

The problem doesnt appear in the {% extends %} or at least not for now. It appears in the

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/alwaysIncluded/*'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/layout.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I tried to remove the **@** but it doesnt change anything.

**Second edit**

[Complete config.yml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwif8wf6fzpnhut/config.txt?dl=0) file (hosted on dropbox cause it's a big file, will either upload it on something better or post it full length if required)

Comment: can you post the entire config.yml files?

Comment: You also have to modify the first "/" to : I think.

Comment: just tried, also tried to use the css from /web directory, doesnt work either...

Comment: Same issue and I don't have any @Bundle annotation, I have implemented the whole AppBundle philosophy and I also have this error. reverting back to 2.6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your composer.json as follows:

```
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.6",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
```

The error comes from assetic in version 2.5.0. The dev version corrects this as explained here:
https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle/issues/119

Answer (score 6):

The following syntax doesn't work any-more with `Symfony 2.6.3` and its default requirements.

If you want to stay with `Symfony 2.6.3` without changing the assetic requirement (using  `dev-master` in production is never a good idea...)

Change (@xxx):

```
{% extends '@MyBundle/layout.html.twig' %}
```

To:

```
{% extends 'MyBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

**Or** stay with `Symfony 2.6.3` and use the `dev-master` requirement of the `assetic-bundle` as suggested in the accepted answer.

**Or** switch back to `Symfony 2.6.1`, I suppose this issue (and the assetic requirement) will be fixed in `Symfony 2.6.4`.

Check out [the issue on Github](https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle/issues/119).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to include `base.html.twig` from one of your templates like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

You need to change it to this:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

[More information here.](https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle/issues/119#issuecomment-69050594)